# Minimality condition while proving ED is a PID.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

In proving the following statement:

Every Euclidean domain is a Principal Ideal Domain.

We are trying to show that every non-zero ideal in Euclidean Domain is a Principal Ideal.
So, let $A(\neq 0)$ be any non-zero ideal of D. Let $b(\neq 0)$ be any element in A s.t $d(b)$ is minimum where $d$ is a euclidean valuation i.e $\exists$ no element $c\in A$ s.t $d(c)\lt d(b)$.

My question is:

Can $d(b)=0$ or it has to be positive always i.e $\gt 0$?

My attempt:

It can be $0$ and I am reading a book which says if $a(\neq 0)\in D$ where $D$ is a euclidean domain s.t $d(a)=0$ then a is a unit.(I need a help proving this statement though!).
So keeping this statment in mind if $d(b)=0$, then $b$ will be unit and hence it will generate the whole Domain, which nowhere violates the conditions of it being a principal ideal domain and hence this case is permissible.
Am I correct? Please throw some light. Thank you.

Comment: d is a function from $D-$ ${0}$ to non-negative numbers i.e. $Z^{+}\cup$ ${0}$ such that $d(ab)\geq d(a)$ $\forall a\neq 0 b\neq 0$ and euclid division algorithm holds in D.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's prove that if $d(a)=0$ for some nonzero $a$, then $a$ is a unit.

Consider the elements  $1$ and $a $. Then, there exists $q $ and $r $ such that  $1=aq+r $ with $r=0$ or $d (r)\lt d (a)=0$. But $d (r)\lt 0$ is not possible and hence  $r=0$. So $1=aq $ and hence  $a $ is a unit.

---

What you wrote is correct; $d(b)$ can be zero. In that case, you have $d(1)=0$.